# Docker created with docker-compose not visible from outside server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've created my docker-compose file with 3 dockerfile attached. Everything is working but currently I'd like to expose outside port 8000.

This is not happening. The host is unreachable :(
What's wrong with this?

```
version: '3'

services:
    elastic:
        build: ./elastic
        ports:
            - 5500:80
        tty: true
        networks:
            - default

    api:
        build: ./api
        ports:
            - 5000:80
        depends_on:
            - elastic
        tty: true
        networks:
            - default

    web:
        build: ./web
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        depends_on:
            - api
        tty: true
        networks:
            - outside
            - default

networks:
  outside:
    external:
        name: docker_gwbridge
```

Comment: So what is the error? What happens when you go to http://<hostip>:8000?

Comment: Host unreachable

Comment: Is this in cloud provider, such as AWS? Or local VM?

Comment: Does the web app currently listen on port 80? Is the container currently running? Did you run a `docker-compose up` after configuring the ports in this file? Are there any firewalls limiting access to the server?

Comment: This is a vps. It works on localhost, if I'll made a curl request within VPS even outside docker it works. It doesn't work if I'll call it from outside, for example from my PC.

Comment: What VPS? What host OS? Sounds like a provider or host firewall issue.

Comment: I think it was something related the port 8000. Anyway now it's working on another port. Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an app running on port other than 80/443. I deployed the app on AWS EC2, and the host could not be reached. In order to make it visible, I had to add an inbound rule in "Security Groups" of EC2 instance, which exposed other ports (8000 in my case).